# Search From a List of Multiple Entries using CTRL+F

Tags: google-chrome, search, browser-addons, find, google-chrome-extensions

I have many documents that I am viewing using Google Chrome and I am searching the PDF document for a word1. If word1 doesn't show up, I search for word2. If word2 doesn't show up, I search for word3. This takes a significant amount of time to retype each of word1, word2, and word3 when it's always the same word.

### Question:

Is there a plugin/extension that anyone knows of where one could provide a list of 5-10 words that they are searching for so that instead of space for a single word to be typed in the CTRL+F search bar, it would instead have a list of prescribed search terms to chose from?

**How to make chrome (or any browser) have a selection list like this?**

**Anyone know of any plugins available?**